# Invalid magic number, when booting from HDD

Tags: boot, grub2, ubuntu-studio

I have a big problem with installation of ubuntustudio-23.04 on my desktop-PC. I could install it from an USB-stick, but get the fault :

```
error: invalid magic number.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
Press any key to continue...
```

after rebooting without stick.
Most discussions here on StackExchange concern booting from USB, but I could boot from it and install UBUNTU Studio on hard disc.
I tried to start the kernel manually from grub like it is written here on
[StackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/1237684/how-to-boot-from-grub-shell), how to boot from grub shell

```
grub>ls
grub>(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd2) (hd2,msdos2) (hd2,msdos1)
grub>ls (hd0,1)/
```

Here I found the boot-directory and by `grub> ls(hd0,1/boot/`the kernel. I put in

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-1007-lowlatency root=/dev/sdc1
```

but got then the error message again `error: invalid magic number` and after

```
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-1007-lowlatency
```

the message `error: you need to load the kernel first` and now I'm going around in circles. I would be obliged for any help to get the actual version 23.04 re-installed

*Remarks here to*:
As you can see from the grub command, I have 3 hard disks, one of them is an SDD, which is `hd0` and `/dev/sdc1`. I checked this and was able to match this correctly. I had two Linux systems installed, one was *Debian 11* and the other one was Ubuntu Studio, which I also upgraded successfully to version 23.04 and all worked perfect until I tried to upgrade *Debian 11* to *Debian 12*, which failed. All that happened now, because I did the fatal fault of putting the command `grub-install /dev/sdc` from the cmd-line of *Debian 12*. Then  the boot sector of `/dev/sdc` was linked to the non-functioning Debian system.
Why did I install an old ubuntu-studio image? Because this was one of the 1000 ideas and researches I did for repairing the system. I tried it before with re-installing the actual one, but this lead to the same results.

Another remarkable point about the USB-stick: It works only once, when writing from my laptop the ISO-file on it with `sudo dd bs=4M if=/home/ruediger/Downloads/ubuntustudio-22.10-dvd-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress oflag=sync` (I got this from somewhere in the internet). When I try to boot from the USB again I got the same invalid magic number error. I spend then again around 8 minutes to load this (or the actual 23.04-version) on the USB stick, to boot from there.